# markdown's bold and italic stop working after including babel package

Tags: pdftex, cyrillic, markdown

I'm having problems with bold and italic options in my pdf file that I get from my Rmarkdown file. I write in Russian so I unclude babel package and after that ** and __ stop working.

Here's my Rmarkdown file. The result is in plain font, the word is not bold.

```
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage[russian]{babel}
---
**Theorem**.
```

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55934481/template.tex) is result of convertion of this Rmd-file to tex.

While this version keeps the word bold:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---
**Theorem**
```

I also tried to change latex engine from pdflatex to xelatex but for xelatex I also should specify some special font that supports cyrillic. If I don't specify mainfont there's no cyrillic letters in the result. And I would really like to stay with the default font.

This works but I don't like the font:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Arial
---

**Теорема**.
```

This doesn't work:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

**Теорема**.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You should show the tex code created by your markdown.

Comment: It's 2kb file, I added the link to it to the post.

Comment: Well the best would be to remove `\usepackage{lmodern}` from your template -- lmodern doesn't support cyrillic. If you can't do it, reset the families with `\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}` and `\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}`

Comment: Thanks! I found default.tex used by Rstudio as a template and removed \usepackage{lmodern} from there. Now everything is fine!

Comment: @EgorIgnatenkov -- since you've found a method that works, perhaps you could add a "self-answer" to describe what you did.  this might help someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recommendation from @Ulrike Fischer worked: I found default.tex used by Rstudio as a template when converting from Rmd to pdf (~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default.tex) and removed \usepackage{lmodern} from there. After that this piece of code compiled correctly:

```
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage[russian]{babel}
---
**Theorem**.
```